# How to use chosings values in a selectInput to populate another selectInput form a csv file

Tags: csv, shiny, reactive

I'm totally new in Shiny (this is my 4th to 5th app). So, by sure my question is far basic, but I'm blocked after reading dozens of posts (I’m pretty sure I don’t even know how to search for the answer I need).

I have a .csv file with 3 columns (and a couple of dozens of files). First 2 are text while 3 is numeric

I’m planning to:

1. using ***1*** to populate one selectInput
2. using the previous chosen value to filter the values to be shown in a second selectInput for ***2***
3. using the value ***3*** to perform my calculations.

Could you please illuminate me on were to go to read the info I need?

Thanks a lot, in advance

Comment: You might want to check [selectizeGroupUI](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/selectizeGroup-module.html).